# A-Frame Drupal integration

Tags: drupal-7, aframe

I try to do a website with drupal 7 and make a VR view of it with A-Frame.

Do you advice me to make a Theme that expose the drupal website into VR ? Or manipulate the html.tpl.php file to put a scene as the default view ?
Have you ever try to make something like that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code for a chance to be helped.

Comment: In fact, I have no code yet, my question is conceptual. I just need some advices on the best approach to make a VR view of drupal

Comment: I just make some test, I changed the default html.tpl.php to encapsulate the A-Frame structure on the main Drupal page. I can see now Aframe in action in my drupal instance but, I don't know where to put the drupal code (php and html). Can I print the drupal website content on a  "<a-plane ></a-plane>" or a  <a-text></a-text> ?